# VSCode Emmets missing

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I deleted some extensions and after that my VSCode Emmet are not working as it used to be. I tried searching for solutions, which led me to going in my Extensions in Setting but the Emmet in extension are also missing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Extensions searchbox input `@builtin`.  Emmet should be listed in the `Features` category.  Note that Emmet can be disabled from vscode but not uninstalled.

If your Emmet extension says it is disabled, then re-enable.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.